# Devise changed config.scoped_views = true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to customize some of the devise views for Hosts and have read tutorials to make views = true in config/initializers/devise.rb

**config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true
```

The devise views I created belong to Hosts (most other deverlopers will use Users, Admin etc)

For the registrations/new.html.erb - updated the H2 heading but this is not being reflected in the browser.

```
<h2>Sign up here and here</h2>
```

at the moment still only shown Sign up as the default heading

Any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: just restart server?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have changed the settings in **config/initializers/devise.rb** to 
**config.scoped_views = true** ---- restart your rails server and it will work